# Understanding mean-variance tautology from Roll's critique

Tags: asset-pricing, capm

One of the points of Roll's critique ([Roll, 1977](https://www.anderson.ucla.edu/documents/areas/fac/finance/1977-2.pdf)) can be summarized as follows (quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll%27s_critique)):

1. **Mean-variance tautology:** Any mean-variance efficient portfolio $R_{p}$ satisfies the CAPM equation exactly:
   $$
   E(R_{i})-R_{f}=\beta_{{ip}}[E(R_{p})-R_{f}].
   $$
   Mean-variance efficiency of the market portfolio is equivalent to the CAPM equation holding. This statement is a mathematical fact, requiring no model assumptions.
   Given a proxy for the market portfolio, testing the CAPM equation is equivalent to testing mean-variance efficiency of the portfolio. **The CAPM is tautological if the market is assumed to be mean-variance efficient.**

Initially I understood this point as follows:

- Statement 1: The CAPM holds.
- Statement 2: The market portfolio is mean-variance efficient.
- On the one hand, we assume Statement 2 to derive Statement 1. But it turns out the two statements are equivalent. Thus, the CAPM is empty in the sense that it does not add anything to the assumption needed to derive it. Hence the tautology. Then there is nothing to test.

Later, I started doubting whether I have interpreted this right. Does the CAPM really assume that the market is mean-variance efficient? If not, how do I understand the last sentence of Roll's point (in bold)?

<sub>Related:

["Testing asset pricing models with Roll's critique in mind"](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75729),

["Roll Critique - CAPM and mean variance tautology?"](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75103)</sub>

Comment: Hi Richard: It's an interesting question. I didn't read the papers but he might be saying that, the CAPM holds without any error term ( no idiosyncratic risk so no $\epsilon$ ) if the market is mean variance efficient.

Comment: @markleeds, if only this, what is the problem with testing the CAPM (the main topic of the paper)?

Comment: Hi Richard: Like I said, I didn't read anything except your posting so I have no idea.  I'll probably have no idea after reading it but I'll try to read it during my travels over the next whatever days. Hopefully someone else can say something useful before then. Who came up  with CAPM anyway ?  Sharpe ? It's been a while since I looked at that material so I forget the history.  I don't know if anyone tested it statistically but I assume it was shot down by the ones that came after it such as the factor models, the Fama-French stuff and APT etc.

Comment: I think the word tautology is a bit strong here. It is perhaps not surprising that a model is equivalent to the assumptions underlying it. It is similar to saying that the Black-Scholes model is tautological to assuming stock returns follow a Geometric Brownian motion. The surprising part is that the CAPM boils down to a single assumption, i.e. the market being MV-efficient. Moreover, I think Roll was the first to show the only if part, i.e. you cannot derive CAPM without this assumption. But as I said before, this is only a subresult Roll uses to make his critique.

Comment: @fes: Nice analogy with the BS model. Thanks. I still have to read his paper. It's a well known paper but it's 48 pages !!!!!!!